# Google Pay using Stripe Android SDK

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I have integrated Google Pay payment option using Stripe Android SDK, but during payment I am getting an ERROR ALERT

> Request Failed
> Unexpected Developer error, please try again later

And in log I am getting

> Status: DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution = null}

```
PaymentConfiguration.init(this, getResources().getString(R.string.stripe_key));

mPaymentsClient = Wallet.getPaymentsClient(this, new Wallet.WalletOptions.Builder().setEnvironment(getEnvironment()).build());
stripe = new Stripe(this, getResources().getString(R.string.stripe_key));

AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(mPaymentsClient.loadPaymentData(createPaymentDataRequest()), this, LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE);

@NonNull
private IsReadyToPayRequest createIsReadyToPayRequest() throws JSONException {
    final JSONArray allowedAuthMethods = new JSONArray();
    allowedAuthMethods.put("PAN_ONLY");
    allowedAuthMethods.put("CRYPTOGRAM_3DS");

    final JSONArray allowedCardNetworks = new JSONArray();
    allowedCardNetworks.put("AMEX");
    allowedCardNetworks.put("DISCOVER");
    allowedCardNetworks.put("MASTERCARD");
    allowedCardNetworks.put("VISA");

    final JSONObject cardParameters = new JSONObject();
    cardParameters.put("allowedAuthMethods", allowedAuthMethods);
    cardParameters.put("allowedCardNetworks", allowedCardNetworks);

    final JSONObject cardPaymentMethod = new JSONObject();
    cardPaymentMethod.put("type", "CARD");
    cardPaymentMethod.put("parameters", cardParameters);

    final JSONArray allowedPaymentMethods = new JSONArray();
    allowedPaymentMethods.put(cardPaymentMethod);

    final JSONObject isReadyToPayRequestJson = new JSONObject();
    isReadyToPayRequestJson.put("apiVersion", 2);
    isReadyToPayRequestJson.put("apiVersionMinor", 0);
    isReadyToPayRequestJson.put("allowedPaymentMethods", allowedPaymentMethods);

    return IsReadyToPayRequest.fromJson(isReadyToPayRequestJson.toString());
}

@NonNull
private PaymentDataRequest createPaymentDataRequest() {
    JSONObject tokenizationSpec = null;
    JSONObject cardPaymentMethod = null;
    JSONObject paymentDataRequest = null;
    try {
        tokenizationSpec = new GooglePayConfig(this).getTokenizationSpecification();
        cardPaymentMethod = new JSONObject()
                .put("type", "CARD")
                .put("parameters", new JSONObject()
                        .put("allowedAuthMethods", new JSONArray()
                                .put("PAN_ONLY")
                                .put("CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"))
                        .put("allowedCardNetworks",
                             new JSONArray()
                                     .put("AMEX")
                                     .put("DISCOVER")
                                     .put("JCB")
                                     .put("MASTERCARD")
                                     .put("VISA"))
                        // require billing address
                        .put("billingAddressRequired", true)
                        .put("billingAddressParameters", new JSONObject()
                                // require full billing address
                                .put("format", "FULL")
                                // require phone number
                                .put("phoneNumberRequired", true)
                            )
                    )
                .put("tokenizationSpecification", tokenizationSpec);

        // create PaymentDataRequest
        paymentDataRequest = new JSONObject()
                .put("apiVersion", 2)
                .put("apiVersionMinor", 0)
                .put("allowedPaymentMethods",
                     new JSONArray().put(cardPaymentMethod))
                .put("transactionInfo", new JSONObject()
                        .put("totalPrice", mPricingDetailsModel.getTotal_cost())
                        .put("totalPriceStatus", "FINAL")
                        .put("currencyCode", "USD"))
                .put("merchantInfo", new JSONObject()
                        .put("merchantName", "SPARKOUT"))
                // require email address
                .put("emailRequired", true);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.Companion.log(e.getMessage());
    }

    return PaymentDataRequest.fromJson(String.valueOf(paymentDataRequest));
}
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch(requestCode) {
            case LOAD_PAYMENT_DATA_REQUEST_CODE: {
                switch(resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK: {
                        if (data != null) {
                            try {
                                onGooglePayResult(data);
                            } catch(Exception e) {
                                Logger.Companion.log(e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                        // Canceled
                        break;
                    }
                    case AutoResolveHelper.RESULT_ERROR: {
                        // Log the status for debugging
                        // Generally there is no need to show an error to
                        // the user as the Google Payment API will do that
                        Status status = AutoResolveHelper.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                        Logger.Companion.log(String.valueOf(status.getStatus()));
                        Logger.Companion.log(status.zza());
                        Logger.Companion.log(String.valueOf(status.getStatusCode()));
                        break;
                    }
                    default: {
                        // Do nothing.
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            default: {
                // Handle any other startActivityForResult calls you may have made.
            }
        }
    }
```

- implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:12.6.1'
- implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.3'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfgUR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is outright absurd, to declare something as `final` and then instantly try to change it again.
The most likely would be: remove all the  `final` keywords and it might actually send a request.